# Excel: Index Match using wild card to match search criteria against all text in a cell?

Tags: excel, formula, lookup

I am using the following Index match code with row function to avoid returning duplicates in my results. The formula currently search's my column `B` on my sheet 'Look Up Supplier Sheet' where it compares the value entered in cell `D11` on sheet 1 and produces the result of my supplier name in column `B` on 'look up supplier sheet'.

So in 'look up supplier sheet' I have the following layout:

```
Name           Description
Supplier A     Catering & Events
Supplier B     Hotels
Supplier C     Legal Solicitor Services
```

Currently my formula is searching the left of the text entered in cell `D11` on sheet 1 by five characters. I have done this so that if someone was to type hotel instead of hotels then a result is still found.

However now I have a problem because if I was to type in legal into my cell `D11` I would get the result `Supplier C`, but if I was to type in solicitor I would not get any results.

I need a way of being able to use some kind of wildcard I suppose which will allow me to enter either legal or solicitors and still get a result

So is there a way of getting my formula to scan the entire cell to search for the matching word, either legal or solicitor in this case?

I am really new to excel so am not sure what I need to do here but I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('Look Up Supplier Sheet'!$A$1:$E$10004,SMALL(IF(LEFT('Look Up Supplier Sheet'!$B$1:$B$10004,5)=LEFT($D$11,5),ROW($B$1:$B$10004)),ROW(1:1)),1)),"",INDEX('Look Up Supplier Sheet'!$A$1:$E$10004,SMALL(IF(LEFT('Look Up Supplier Sheet'!$B$1:$B$10004,5)=LEFT($D$11,5),ROW($B$1:$B$10004)),ROW(1:1)),1))
```

Comment: I presume also from your use of ISERROR that this needs to be compatible with Excel 2003?

Comment: No not really I am only really concerned with it working in 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, over a range of that size, operating an array formula with an error clause is hugely inefficient and will force Excel to perform much more calculation than is actually necessary. See here for an explanation if you're interested:

https://superuser.com/questions/812727/look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-all-multiple-corresponding-values/812848#812848

Secondly, using ROW($B$1:$B$10004) for the *value_if_true* clause to be passed to INDEX is risky. If, for example, you decided to amend your range at some point, e.g. to $B$**2**:$B$10005, and so amended the above part of your formula to ROW($B$**2**:$B$10005), you might be disappointed to see that your formula no longer gave correct results. Far more rigorous is a construction such as:

```
ROW($B$1:$B$10004)-MIN(ROW($B$1:$B$10004))+1
```

or (as some prefer):

```
ROW($B$1:$B$10004)-ROW($B$1)+1
```

Thirdly, ROWS($1:1) is a more rigorous choice than ROW(1:1) for SMALL's *k* parameter.

Overall, then, first enter this (non-array) formula in a cell somewhere, e.g. C1:

```
=COUNTIF('Look Up Supplier Sheet'!$B$1:$B$10004,"*"&$D$11&"*")
```

The required array formula** is then:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)>$C$1,"",INDEX('Look Up Supplier Sheet'!$A$1:$D$10004,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$D$11&" "," "&'Look Up Supplier Sheet'!$B$1:$B$10004&" ")),ROW($B$1:$B$10004)-MIN(ROW($B$1:$B$10004))+1),ROWS($1:1)),1))
```

Copy this formula down (though not the one in C1) until you start to get blanks for the results.

Regards